# keyboard layout explanation creator tool

Tags: layout, keyboard, controls

In contrast to most other inquiries on this topic, I do not wish to create a new layout for my keyboard. Rather, I aim to provide explanations for each key similar to those found in a computer game. This entails adding arrows pointing to each key along with corresponding text. My question is whether there exists a tool tailored for this specific purpose. I am hesitant to embark on this endeavor using Inkscape.

A tool to create fast something like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPdB5.jpg)

I tried to search but all the results were about creating new different keyboard layouts for the pc.